# Обработка чекбокса в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно обработать чекбокс в контроллере Laravel.
Не могу реализовать отправку состояния чекбокса при клике на него в контроллер через форму.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался динамически создать названия функций(знаю что так не работает), но может есть другой способ решения данной проблемы?

```
@extends('layouts/app')
@section('content')
<div>
 <p>ToDoList</p>
 <a href="newTasksList">Начать новый список задач</a>
  <form action={{url('task')}} method="POST">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <label for="Task">Добавить новую задачу</label>
      <input type='text' name='content' id='task-name' />
      <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
  </form>
</div>
    @if(count($tasks)>0)
        <div>
        <p>Текущие задачи</p>
        <ol>
            @foreach($tasks as $task)
            <li>
                 <form method = "POST" class = "my_form" id="{{$task->id}}" action="checkboxChange/{{$task->id}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type = "checkbox" onchange="formSend_{{$task->id}}()" name = "checkbox{{$task->id}}">
                 </form>
                 <span>{{$task->content}}</span>
                 <a href = "delete/{{$task->id}}">Х</a>
            </li>
             @endforeach
        </ol>
        <a href = "deleteCompleted">Удалить выполненные задачи</a>
        <div/>
     @endif
@endsection
    <script>
        var formsSend = () => document.querySelectorAll("my_form").submit();
        for(let i=0;i<formsSend.length;i++){
            var id = formsSend[i].id;
            var formSend_+id = () => formsSend[i].submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blade

```
           <form method="POST" id = "my_form" action="/my-url">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <input type="checkbox" onchange="formSend()" name = "my_ch">

             <button type="submit">GO</button>
        </form>

    <script>

        let formSend = () => document.getElementById("my_form").submit();

    </script>
```

Controller

```
public function myMethod(Request $request) {

    if('on' == $request->get('my_ch')) {
        dd('checked');
    }

}
```

Comment: Да, только надо как-то реализовать без button, потому что в интерфейсе его не должно быть.

Comment: То есть по нажатию на чекбокс автоматом должны отправляться данные на обработку в контроллер.

Comment: @Данила Тогда вам нужно установить слушатель на чекбокс, который отправит форму

Comment: @Данила Изменил ответ

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Да, это работает для одной формы, но у меня генерируется массив форм.

Comment: @Данила ну так измените `my-form` с id на class, либо в цикле к id `my-form` добавляйте ключ итерации `my-from1`

Comment: jQuery вам в помощь. $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).parent().submit();
        }
    });